# How repartition spark with one (or several) very big partitions?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, partition

I have a DataFrame with 10 paritions but 90% of the data belongs to 1 or 2 partitions. If I invoke `dataFrame.coalesce(10)` this splits each partition into 10 parts while this is not neccessary for 8 partitions. Is there a way to split only partitions with data into more parts then others?

Comment: `coalesce` doesn't work like that. If you have 10 partitions with data only in one partition and you execute `coalesce(20)` the data will remain in the partition it was unless you specify `shuffle = true` in coalesce which is essentially equal to `repartition`. If you wanna distribute data equally among partitions, use `repartition`. But it'll be expensive because it involves shuffling the data over the network.

Comment: But again if I call `repartition` on some `date` field it creates 10 partitions, if I pass partition number to that method all 10 partition will be splitted. Is there a way to split only one partition?

Comment: Could you clarify why it matters that this coalesce operation only changes the larger partitions?